# python create dataframe from elasticsearch result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, elasticsearch

I have query result from elasticsearch in following format:

```
[

{
    "_index": "product",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "23234sdf",
    "_score": 2.2295187,
    "_source": {
        "SERP_KEY": "",
        "r_variant_info": "",
        "s_asin": "",
        "pid": "394",
        "r_gtin": "00838128000547",        
        "additional_attributes_remarks": "publisher:0|size:0",            
        "s_gtin": "",            
        "r_category": "",
        "confidence_score": "2.4545",      
        "title_match": "45.45"
    }
},
{
    "_index": "product",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "23234sdf",
    "_score": 2.2295187,
    "_source": {
        "SERP_KEY": "",
        "r_variant_info": "",
        "s_asin": "",
        "pid": "394",
        "r_gtin": "00838128000547",        
        "additional_attributes_remarks": "publisher:0|size:0",            
        "s_gtin": "",            
        "r_category": "",
        "confidence_score": "2.4545",      
        "title_match": "45.45"
    }
},

]
```

I am trying to load `_source` field along with `_id` also into dataframe.

I tried this:

```
def fetch_records_from_elasticsearch_index(index, filter_json):
    search_param = prepare_es_body(filter_json_dict=filter_json)
    response = settings.ES.search(index=index, body=search_param, size=10)

    if len(response['hits']['hits']) > 0:
        import pandas as pd

        all_hits = response['hits']['hits']
        # return all_hits
        # export es hits to pandas dataframe
        df = pd.concat(map(pd.DataFrame.from_dict, all_hits), axis=1)['_source'].T

        return df
    else:
        return 0
```

`df` contains `_source` field only, but I also want to add `_id` field to it.

Here's the df output format:

```
{

"AdminEdit": [
    "False",
    "False",
    "False",
    "False",        
],
"Group": [
    "Grp2",
    "Grp2",
    "Grp2",
    "Grp2"       
],

}
```

How can I add `_id` to it?

Comment: `from pandas.io import json; print (json.json_normalize(response))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches to solve this:

1. direct code

   ```
   import pandas as pd
   df = pd.json_normalize(all_hits)
   ```
2. improvement to your code

   ```
   import json
   import pandas as pd
   df = pd.concat(map(pd.DataFrame.from_dict, all_hits), axis=1)['_source'].T
   df["_id"] = [i["_id"] for i in all_hits]
   ```

The JSON used is:

```
all_hits = [

{
    "_index": "product",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "23234sdg",
    "_score": 2.2295187,
    "_source": {
        "SERP_KEY": "",
        "r_variant_info": "",
        "s_asin": "",
        "pid": "394",
        "r_gtin": "00838128000547",        
        "additional_attributes_remarks": "publisher:0|size:0",            
        "s_gtin": "",            
        "r_category": "",
        "confidence_score": "2.4545",      
        "title_match": "45.45"
    }
},
{
    "_index": "product",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "23234sdf",
    "_score": 2.2295187,
    "_source": {
        "SERP_KEY": "",
        "r_variant_info": "",
        "s_asin": "",
        "pid": "394",
        "r_gtin": "00838128000547",        
        "additional_attributes_remarks": "publisher:0|size:0",            
        "s_gtin": "",            
        "r_category": "",
        "confidence_score": "2.4545",      
        "title_match": "45.45"
    }
},

]
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this:

```
response = '''
[
{
    "_index": "product",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "23234sdf",
    "_score": 2.2295187,
    "_source": {
        "SERP_KEY": "",
        "r_variant_info": "",
        "s_asin": "",
        "pid": "394",
        "r_gtin": "00838128000547",        
        "additional_attributes_remarks": "publisher:0|size:0",            
        "s_gtin": "",            
        "r_category": "",
        "confidence_score": "2.4545",      
        "title_match": "45.45"
    }
},
{
    "_index": "product",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "23234sdf",
    "_score": 2.2295187,
    "_source": {
        "SERP_KEY": "",
        "r_variant_info": "",
        "s_asin": "",
        "pid": "394",
        "r_gtin": "00838128000547",        
        "additional_attributes_remarks": "publisher:0|size:0",            
        "s_gtin": "",            
        "r_category": "",
        "confidence_score": "2.4545",      
        "title_match": "45.45"
    }
}
]
'''

from pandas.io import json as js
import json

data = json.loads(response)
df = js.json_normalize(data)
print(df.columns)
```

These are the columns that you get in the final dataframe:

```
Index(['_id', '_index', '_score', '_source.SERP_KEY',
       '_source.additional_attributes_remarks', '_source.confidence_score',
       '_source.pid', '_source.r_category', '_source.r_gtin',
       '_source.r_variant_info', '_source.s_asin', '_source.s_gtin',
       '_source.title_match', '_type'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: yes.. the response and output fields may differ. That's why I said `format`.

Comment: IIUC, you wanted the _id and _source fields in the output, I guess the above solution is getting them now?